# Python script proxy checker, how to make it properly?

Tags: python, proxy, request

Recently without having much coding knowledge I tried to make my own proxy/ip info checker python script which is below:

```
import requests
import json
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()


def get_location():
    proxyk = line
    proxyl = proxyk.strip()
    pip, port = proxyl.split(':')
    
    #print(port)
    #pro_ip = get_ip()
    #print(pip)            
    try:
        iresponse = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/ip',
            headers = {'User-Agent':str(ua.random)}, 
            timeout=10,  
            proxies=dict(http='socks5h://{proxyl}',
                        https='socks5h://{proxyl}')).json()
                        
        ip = iresponse["origin"]
        checker = iresponse["origin"]
        response = requests.get(f'https://ipapi.co/{ip}/json/',
                    headers = {'User-Agent':str(ua.random)}).json()
        print(checker)
    
    except:
        iresponse = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/ip',
            headers = {'User-Agent':str(ua.random)},
            timeout=10).json()
        checker = iresponse["origin"]
        response = requests.get(f'https://ipapi.co/{pip}/json/',
                    headers = {'User-Agent':str(ua.random)}).json()
        print(checker)


    location_data = {
        "ip": pip,
        "proxy": proxyl,
        "city": response.get("city"),
        "region": response.get("region"),
        "country": response.get("country_name"),
        "postal": response.get("postal"),
        "timezone": response.get("timezone"),
        "org": response.get("org"),
        "checker": checker
    }
    return location_data


with open('det.txt', 'w') as z:
#file = input("Enter a File Here:   ")
    with open('proxy.txt', "r") as p:
        lines = ""
        for line in p.readlines():
            lines = lines + line
            print(line)

            z.write(str(get_location()))
            #z.write(",")
            #z.write(line)
            #z.write(",")
            #z.write(ip)
            
            z.write('\r\n')
```

Everytime I run the script it skips the *try:* block because of error. I made that block for checking live proxies but all proxies bypassed!

Expecting that the script will make request using given proxies (from file) and store the response.

Comment: If you didn't use a blanket `except:` you would see what the problem is.

Comment: ConnectionError: SOCKSHTTPConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /ip (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSConnection object at 0x000001838E4F0B20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

Comment: This error comes up.

Comment: I don't understand!  Googled couple of times and failed to find any solution..

Comment: If you print `proxyk` inside `get_location`, is the output what you expect?

Comment: No... This is not crawler, I already have proxies in text file proxy.txt... Some proxies are port forwarding, so I need the public one using the proxy. Then details of the public proxy.